# java.util.Scanner does not yield correct result

Tags: java, string, date, java.util.scanner

In following code, if coverDate is "June 16 - June 29, 2014", then at the end of while loop the dates array has [16, 2014]. It should be [16, 29, 2014]

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(coverDate);
List<Integer> dates = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        dates.add(scanner.nextInt());
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
 }

scanner.close();
```

Can someone help me get a desired result?

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe `29,` is interpreted as a double (not int) because of the comma?

Comment: Or maybe as a `String`

Comment: Makes sense, how do I get desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `scanner.hasNextInt()`, the `29` is parsed *along* with the comma, i.e. the next token is `29,`. Hence `scanner.hasNextInt()` would return false. This is because the delimiter is whitespace.

One hacky way to resolve it is by adjusting the delimiter to include the comma:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace}+,]");
```

Answer (score 2):

A Scanner uses the whitespace as a default delimiter. 
In your case, the comma is taken with the number 29, so this token is not considered a valid number.

You can set the delimiter with `useDelimiter()`, which accepts a regex.
I suggest you use the `\D` delimiter, which stands for "non-digit" :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(coverDate).useDelimiter("\\D");
```